# Find the eigenvalues ​with row exchanges

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Since the eigenvalues ​​of a diagonal matrix are the elements on the diagonal, I was wondering if, by swapping the rows to obtain a diagonal matrix, the eigenvalues ​​continue to be the elements on the diagonal?

for example, having the matrix A:
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 &   \dots  & 0 &\alpha \\
    -\alpha  \\
    & \ \ddots \\
    &  & -\alpha &  0
\end{bmatrix}

and doing line swaps in order to have:

\begin{bmatrix}
    -\alpha & \dots & \dots& 0  \\
    & \ \ddots \\
    &  & -\alpha & \\
    &&&\alpha
\end{bmatrix}

and doing line swaps in order to have: $\lambda_1 = (-1)^{n-1}\;\,\alpha$ and $\lambda_2 = (-1)^{n}\;\alpha$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvalues of $\begin{bmatrix}& 1 \\ -1 & \end{bmatrix}$ are $i$ and $-i$,
but the eigenvalues of $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ & -1 \end{bmatrix}$ are $1$ and $-1$.

---

If $P$ is an invertible matrix like a [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix), then $PAP^{-1}$ has the same eigenvalues as $A$. But this is not true of $PA$ (permuting rows of $A$) .